# Operations in Hive

Tags: hive, bigdata

I'm new to hive and came across Operations of Hive. 
When I have asked this to my peers. I'm getting different answers.

1. Someone saying that Built-in operators.
2. Some are saying ACID and CRUD
3. Rest of all saying DML and DDL operations.

Can anyone suggest me the proper one?

Comment: Proper one for what purpose?

Comment: I need to give session on this topic @leftjoin